# Elastic ExistsRequst for field value and field type

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-api

I'm working on a project creating integration tests and the data I have includes all the schema updates people have done in the past.  For example My "documents" field has a property of `user`, which has been an array in the past, but is now an Object.

I'm trying to write an integration test that will ONLY use a `document` if the `user` type is Object, not array.

Is there a way to do this with an `ExistsQuery`?  So far I have not been able to find anything. Here's my current query which brings back inconsistent data:

```
GET _search
{
 "query" : {
   "bool" : {
     "must" : {
       "exists" : {
         "document.user"
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Ideally I'd like to check for `document.user[]` and filter those values out.

Comment: I believe you will have to use a script to see if the user is list or object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use script query like below

```
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": "if (doc['document.keyword'].size()==1) return true;"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to using painless scripts so please forgive me, but is that the entire JSON to use?  Nothing else?  I would assume you'd need to know about `document.user`, no?

Comment: @Dan please change "document" to your field name in query. Test it out and let me know if you face any issue

Comment: which field should I change it to, "document" or "user"?   Inside the ES doc we literally have a property called "document" (as crazy as that sounds)

So should I change it to ```"script": "if (doc['document.user.keyword'].size()==1) return true;```

Comment: @Dan can you add sample document and your mapping

Comment: Unfort. no, I cannot.  This issue is on a corp account which I cannot share.

Comment: @Dan try document.user.keyword, check if it works. If data type of field document is nested then you will need to use nested query